# 'Cannot delete revision 143047 above applied patches' (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial

When I do hg qnew name.patch > hg qrefresh > hg qfinish name.patch I get 'cannot delete revision 143047 above applied patches'.  I can see the error message replicated here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-September/024525.html

However I'm struggling to work out how to rectify this so I can submit a patch to be reviewed.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have more than one patch in your patch queue. My guess is that the repository looks like this before you start:

```
... [x] --- [y] --- <p>
```

where `[ ]` is a normal changeset and `< >` is an applied MQ patch. You then have some modifications in the working copy that you put into the new patch with `hg qnew` and get:

```
... [x] --- [y] --- <p> --- <o>
```

When you run `hg qfinish` you ask Mercurial to make `<o>` a regular commit like this:

```
... [x] --- [y] --- <p> --- [o]
```

However, this is an impossible situation since you can't `hg qpop` the patch `<p>` then — doing so would also have to delete the changeset `[o]`.

Basically: you must `hg qfinish` patches from the *beginning* of your patch queue, not from the top.

Finally: you normally *don't* have to turn your MQ patches into regular commits in order to submit them for review. That is, you can run `hg export` on the applied MQ patches just fine, just like you can run `hg email` and all other commands on the applied patches. Infact, the applied patches *are* already regular commits and all the normal commands work on them. It is only `hg push` that behaves differently because it won't let you push changesets representing applied MQ patches.

Comment: OK, many thanks for that.  Is there a straightforward way of me sorting out the issue with my patch queue so I can simply do hg qnew name.patch > hg qrefresh?  Also, will simply doing hg qnew name.patch > hg qrefresh then generate a patch with all my changes (i.e. without doing hg export etc) for someone to review?

Comment: @MichaelNares: don't forget to up-vote helpful answers. Like I said, applied MQ patches are regular changesets, so you can send them to someone for review in whatever manner you like. MQ allows you to go back and revise your commits later — that's all it adds. `hg export` is really the normal way to prepare a patch for review purposes: the receiver can use `hg import` to apply it. MQ is not needed for reviews, MQ is a tool that *you* use so you can better respond to review comments.